# Trouble with deserializing JSON in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

Need help in deserializing of the following responce to object. I'm new in c# so I hope you won't judge strict)

```
    {"getappdata":
    {"general":
        {"message":""},
        "pool":
            {"hashrate":6699750,
            "workers":8873,
            "basis_pps":0.132769,
            "alt_pps":0,
            "alt_bonus":0},
        "ltc_exchange_rates":
            {"USD":"13",
            "EUR":"9.69"},
        "user":
            {"username":"overstorm",
            "balance":4.63247039,
            "hashrate":0,
            "sharerate":0,
            "invalid_share_rate":0},
        "worker":[
            {"name":"overstorm.1",
            "hashrate":0,"active":0,
            "monitoring":1},
            {"name":"overstorm.2",
            "hashrate":0,"active":0,
            "monitoring":1}],
        "earnings":
            {"basis":[],
            "alt":[],
            "24h_total":0,
            "24h_basis":0,
            "24h_alt":0,
            "24h_affiliate":0,
            "48h_total":0,
            "48h_basis":0,
            "48h_alt":0,
            "48h_affiliate":0}
    }
}
```

The class I created looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
        public class GetAppData
        {
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "general")]
            public General general { get; set; }




            [Serializable]
            public class General
            {
                [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "message")]
                public string msg { get; set; }
                [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "pool")]
                public Pool pool { get; set; }
                [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ltc_exchange_rates")]
                public Erates erates { get; set; }
                [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user")]
                public User user { get; set; }
                [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "worker")]
                public IList<Worker> workers { get; set; }
                [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "earnings")]
                public Earnings earnings { get; set; }
                public T DeSerializeData<T>(string t)
                {
                    return (new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(t));
                }

                [Serializable]                
                public class Msg
                {
                    public string msg { get; set; }
                    public T DeSerializeData<T>(string t)
                    {
                        return (new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(t));
                    }
                }


                [Serializable]
                public class Pool
                {
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "hashrate")]
                    public int hashrate { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "workers")]
                    public int Workers { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "basis_pps")]
                    public double basis_pps { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "alt_pps")]
                    public double alt_pps { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "alt_bonus")]
                    public double alt_bonus { get; set; }
                }

                [Serializable]
                public class Erates
                {
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "USD")]
                    public double USD { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "EUR")]
                    public double EUR { get; set; }

                    public T DeSerializeData<T>(string t)
                    {
                        return (new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(t));
                    }
                }

                [Serializable]
                public class User
                {
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "username")]
                    public string Username { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "balance")]
                    public double Balance { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "hashrate")]
                    public double Hashrate { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sharerate")]
                    public double Sharerate { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "invalid_share_rate")]
                    public double Invalid_Share_Rates { get; set; }

                    public T DeSerializeData<T>(string t)
                    {
                        return (new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(t));
                    }
                }

                [Serializable]
                public class Worker
                {
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
                    public string Name { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "hashrate")]
                    public int hashrate { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "active")]
                    public string active { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "monitoring")]
                    public string monitoring { get; set; }

                    public T DeSerializeData<T>(string t)
                    {
                        return (new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(t));
                    }
                }

                [Serializable]
                public class Earnings
                {
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "basis")]
                    public IList<string> basis { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "alt")]
                    public IList<string> alt { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "24h_total")]
                    public string DayTotal { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "24h_basis")]
                    public string DayBasis { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "24h_alt")]
                    public string DayAlt { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "24h_affiliate")]
                    public string DayAffiliate { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "48h_total")]
                    public string TwoDaysTotal { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "48h_basis")]
                    public string TwoDaysBasis { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "48h_alt")]
                    public string TwoDaysAlt { get; set; }
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "48h_affiliate")]
                    public string TwoDaysAffiliate { get; set; }

                    public T DeSerializeData<T>(string t)
                    {
                        return (new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(t));
                    }
                }
            }


            public T DeSerializeData<T>(string t)
            {
                return (new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(t));
            }
        }
```

And that's how I try to deserialize:

```
   GetAppData GAD = new GetAppData();
    GAD = jss.Deserialize<GetAppData>(jsonString);
```

And that's what my GAD looks like

```
{JSON_Test.Form1.GetAppData}
```

Please help) Google is already tired of me)

Comment: Why are you creating a new `GetAppData` if you're about to overwrite the value of `GAD` with something else? Why not just `GetAppData appData = jss.Deserialize<GetAppData>(jsonString)`? And what do you mean by "and that's what my GAD looks like"?

Comment: "What my GAD looks like" is the value of the object. I have many mistakes in code. I'm still learning. Sorry

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "the value of the object"? Have you just called `ToString` on it? Inspected it in the debugger? I suspect you'll find that it's just because you haven't overridden `ToString`... expand the object in the debugger and you'll be able to see all the properties etc.

Comment: I've inspected it in debugger. The value of the object itself is exactly as I wrote it and all of it's properties are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you misunderstand your JSON structure. For better understanding you can use [json viever](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/). You can also use [json2csharp.com/](http://json2csharp.com/) to generate youd data class based on JSON sample

Your data structure should look (using Newtonsoft JSON):

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSON>(s);


    public class JSON
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "getappdata")]
        public GetAppData getappdata { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class General
    {
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "message")]
       public string msg { get; set; }
    }

   [Serializable]
   public class GetAppData
   {
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "general")]
       public General general { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "pool")]
       public Pool pool { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ltc_exchange_rates")]
       public Erates erates { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user")]
       public User user { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "worker")]
       public IList<Worker> workers { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "earnings")]
       public Earnings earnings { get; set; }
   }

   [Serializable]                
   public class Msg
   {
       public string msg { get; set; }

   }


   [Serializable]
   public class Pool
   {
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "hashrate")]
       public int hashrate { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "workers")]
       public int Workers { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "basis_pps")]
       public double basis_pps { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "alt_pps")]
       public double alt_pps { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "alt_bonus")]
       public double alt_bonus { get; set; }
   }

   [Serializable]
   public class Erates
   {
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "USD")]
       public double USD { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "EUR")]
       public double EUR { get; set; }


   }

   [Serializable]
   public class User
   {
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "username")]
       public string Username { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "balance")]
       public double Balance { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "hashrate")]
       public double Hashrate { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sharerate")]
       public double Sharerate { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "invalid_share_rate")]
       public double Invalid_Share_Rates { get; set; }


   }

   [Serializable]
   public class Worker
   {
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
       public string Name { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "hashrate")]
       public int hashrate { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "active")]
       public string active { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "monitoring")]
       public string monitoring { get; set; }


   }

   [Serializable]
   public class Earnings
   {
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "basis")]
       public IList<string> basis { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "alt")]
       public IList<string> alt { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "24h_total")]
       public string DayTotal { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "24h_basis")]
       public string DayBasis { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "24h_alt")]
       public string DayAlt { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "24h_affiliate")]
       public string DayAffiliate { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "48h_total")]
       public string TwoDaysTotal { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "48h_basis")]
       public string TwoDaysBasis { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "48h_alt")]
       public string TwoDaysAlt { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "48h_affiliate")]
       public string TwoDaysAffiliate { get; set; }


   }
```